# What is the meaning of "for starters"

Tags: sentence-meaning

Here is the sentence:

> Others came along who said they wanted to be the best, but I didn’t believe them. They didn’t even look me in the eye **for starters.**
>
> *From: "Cristiano Ronaldo—the biography" by Guillem Balagué.*

I don't know what the author means by saying "They didn’t even look me in the eye for starters." Specifically, **I don't know what "for starters" means here and how it relates to the sentence.**

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried looking this up in a dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [is an idiom](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for-starters).  The writer says "I didn't believe them".  Then the writer gives a reason to answer the question "Why didn't you believe them".  The reason is "They didn't look me in the eye."

But there are others reasons. The author says this is just the *start* of a list of reasons that he had.  He might give some more reasons, or he might not tell you the other ones.  To tell you that this is just the start, he uses "for starters".

Another example:

> I ride my bike to work.  It keeps me fit, for starters. But it also saves money and it is good for the environment.

> Who will I invite to the party?  Well, my girlfriend, for starters. But I'll also ask my work colleagues and my friends from the club.

Comment: Me: Dad, why can't I borrow the car? Dad: For starters, you can't drive.

Comment: @James:  I thought that starter means beginner. Now I get this. I really appreciate your explanations and examples. Thanks a lot, James!!